# Iptables port forwarding localhost on blocked port

Tags: linux, iptables

I am currently trying to forward port 80 to port 4999 so that 80 is exposed but 4999 is not. After looking into this, I found that the tabels below do what I want successfully, but I do not understand how they work. Could anyone describe to me what is going on here and tell me if this causes any security problems?

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [325:20003]
:INPUT ACCEPT [404:24676]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [360:25177]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [360:25177]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 4999
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4999 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 80
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [8142:1141863]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4999 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
COMMIT
```

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the question, but I don't see why you think you would have improved your security at all by having a service listen on an alternate port, and the NAT it so that traffic destined for the standard port is redirected.  No particular port is any more or less secure then any other.  The security is all about the application that is listening to that port.

Comment: In terms of security, I was just curious if this would make me more vulnerable since I did not understand it what it was doing. The forwarding is a requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The first prerouting rule change incoming port 80 trafic to port 4999 and the firs input rule accept it.

The second prerouting rule change the port 4999 traffic to port 80 and the second input rule drop it.

I think change the second prerouting rule to -j DROP will do the job better.

Or change de default INPUT policy to DROP, and delete the second INPUT rule.

Like Zoredache told, it has no much sense.

Comment: So are you saying that when forwarding a port locally it does not go through the nat table again? For example, would the behavior be different if i were forwarding to another machine?

Comment: Let see another example: when a packet comes, iptables apply the prerouting chain (nat table), if it match your rules the destination port is changed. Then go to input chain (filter table), if it match your first rule is accepted, if not is dropped. There is not forwarding table here.